# In an xState action how can I access the private _state?

Tags: reactjs, xstate

The scenario: when **onEntry** to the **submit state** it fires a defined **saveData** action. This action persists the form data, the catch is I can’t get access to the data although if I hardcode a dataset object and use that it works. I can see the data I need is located in *machine._state* but this is private and I can't figure out how to access it. Could someone tell me how, please?

```
[saveData]: assign((ctx, ev) => {
        const { machines = {}, data, form, } = ctx;
        const { order } = form;
        const index = 0;
        const currentStep = order[index];
        const machine = machines[currentStep]; //machine has a private _state that I need access to
}),
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share a full code example? Are the machines in ctx.machines spawned?

Comment: I'm sorry, the code base is at work and I can't access it for 3 days. I am new to xState and although I looked up "spawn" in the docs I still can't answer your question. I added a screenshot I had in a chat that shows the data exists in the context. If that helps any...